# In KineticJS, what is the difference between the "click" event and the "contentClick" event?

Tags: javascript, events, kineticjs

**Can someone explain the difference between the "click" event and the "contentClick" event ?**

```
stage.on("contentClick", function(e) {
    console.log("stage contentClick");
})

stage.on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("stage click");
})

//Both events get fired equally
```

I've already noticed that "contentClick" seems to work on the stage only :

```
rect.on("contentClick", function(e) {
    //This never gets fired
    console.log("rect contentClick");
})
```

... and "contentClick" doesn't play well with cancelBubble :

```
rect.on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("rect click");
    e.cancelBubble = true;
})

stage.on("contentClick", function(e) {
    //This fires even though cancelBubble should prevent it
    console.log("stage contentClick");
})
```

Apart from these differences, what exactly IS "contentClick" and what is it usually used for ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `contentEvent` will fired on events on DOM element. First argument of callback is special Kinetic event object, you can access to native DOM event object via `evt` property (for v.5.1.0):

```
stage.on("contentClick", function(e) {
  var nativeEvent = e.evt;
  console.log("stage contentClick", e);
});
```

Other events (with no 'content' prefix) are fired on Kinetic Node events.
Look at demo: http://jsbin.com/pomemo/1/edit

Try to click on image. You will see two events in console `contentClick` (bubbled from canvas element) and `click` ("bubled" from Kinetic.Image).
Then try to click on empty space. You will see only one event `contentClick` and no `click` event (because you didn't click on any Kinetic.Node)

Comment: Is there any way I can cancel the contentClick event after the "click" event on the image is fired ?

Comment: Need to understand your purpose. Why do you need it?

Comment: Sure, and there might be a better way. I just need a "click" event on the stage but I don't want it to be fired on nodes. Currently "contentClick" fires for stage+nodes and "click" doesn't fire at all in empty regions of the stage.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when the event is triggered on a specific node, the targetNode value in the event is set to that node.... when the event is triggered only by clicking on the stage, then targetNode is NOT set on the event.

So, I set my handler to test for existence of targetNode:

```
UIUtils_stageClick = function(event){
// unselect anything, only if we did not click on a card.... clicking on the table background only
if (!event.targetNode) {
    voidFunctions_clearSelection();
}
    // hide any error message flag or card label tag
    UIUtils_hideErrorToolTip();
    UIUtils_hideCardToolTip();
    window.game.stage.draw();
```

}